# Proving the points are on the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that points A, B, C, and D are all on one plane if and only if AD·(AB×AC) = 0.

I know that |AD·(AB×AC)| is the volume of parallelepiped determined by the four points A, B, C, and D but I am not sure how to take this idea forward to prove this statement.

Comment: In this case the volume of the parallelepiped has no volume, then $$\vec{AD}\cdot (\vec{AB}\times \vec{AC})=\vec{0}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC} = 0$, then $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are parallel, so $A,B,C$ are collinear, so $A,B,C,D$ are coplanar.

If $v := \vec{AB} \times \vec{AC} \neq 0$, then $A,B,C$ are not collinear, so there is exactly one plane through them, namely the plane $\{X \in \mathbb R^3: \vec{AX} \cdot v = 0\}$. It is easy to show that $A,B,C$ lie in this plane, and it is also easy to see that $D$ lies in this plane if and only if $\vec{AD}\cdot(\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In the other case take $$\vec{AC}=\alpha\vec{AB}+\beta\vec{BC}$$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are real numbers and compute the product above.

Comment: Oh yeah I see, I'll try that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Pick coordinates on your world so that $A$ is the origin, and so that $B$ and $C$ both lie in the $xy$-plane. (This is possible even if $A, B, $ and $C$ are collinear, indeed, in that case there are many choices for the $xy$-plane!)

Now $AB$ and $AC$ are both vectors in the $xy$-plane, so $n = AB \times AC$ is along the $z$-axis. If $AD \cdot n = 0$, then $AD$ has no $z$ component, and hence $D$, too, must lie in the $xy$-plane.

This is an instance of the general principle: "Choose a coordinate system in which your problem is easy to solve."

Hidden in this particular answer is an assumption about the cross-product, namely, that it's invariant under changes in coordinates. Fortunately, there's a coordinate-free description that shows this is the case, but you shouldn't ignore this kind of thing when you try to do coordinate-adapted proofs.

Comment: Oh I see, got it. Thank you